# Is there any way to specify type in scala dynamically

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new in Spark, Scala, so sorry for stupid question. So I have a number of tables:

> table_a, table_b, ...

and number of corresponding types for these tables

> case class classA(...), case class classB(...), ...

Then I need to write a methods that read data from these tables and create dataset:

```
def getDataFromSource: Dataset[classA] = {
       val df: DataFrame = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table_a")
       df.as[classA]
}
```

The same for other tables and types. Is there any way to avoid routine code - I mean individual fucntion for each table and get by with one? For example:

```
def getDataFromSource[T: Encoder](table_name: String): Dataset[T] = {
       val df: DataFrame = spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM $table_name")
       df.as[T]
}
```

Then create list of pairs (table_name, type_name):

```
val tableTypePairs = List(("table_a", classA), ("table_b", classB), ...)
```

Then to call it using foreach:

```
tableTypePairs.foreach(tupl => getDataFromSource[what should I put here?](tupl._1))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```scala
def getDataFromSource[T](table_name: String, encoder: Encoder[T]): Dataset[T] =
  spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM $table_name").as(encoder)

val tableTypePairs = List(
  "table_a" -> implicitly[Encoder[classA]],
  "table_b" -> implicitly[Encoder[classB]]
)

tableTypePairs.foreach {
  case (table, enc) =>
    getDataFromSource(table, enc)
}
```

Note that this is a case of discarding a value, which is a bit of a code smell.  Since `Encoder` is invariant, `tableTypePairs` isn't going to have that useful of a type, and neither would something like

```scala
tableTypePairs.map {
  case (table, enc) =>
    getDataFromSource(table, enc)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pass the `Class` to the method, this way the generic type `T` will be inferred:

```scala
def getDataFromSource[T: Encoder](table_name: String, clazz: Class[T]): Dataset[T] = {
       val df: DataFrame = spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM $table_name")
       df.as[T]
}

tableTypePairs.foreach { case (table name, clazz) => getDataFromSource(tableName, clazz) }
```

But then I'm not sure of how you'll be able to exploit this list of `Dataset` without `.asInstanceOf`.